# how to fetch first 3 string from column 1 file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 

# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Python Scripts/TextFile.txt") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 

print(data.head(20))

df1 = data[data.columns[0]]

df1.columns = ['code']

df1.code = df1.code.str.slice(0, 3)
```

I want to fetch first 3 words from file. But gives me this error

```
 File "C:\Python Scripts\Test.py", line 17, in <module>
    df1.code = df1.code.str.slice(0, 3)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'code'
```

What am i doing wrong here .
Am i not supposed to do like this.
I tried other methods but not successful

Comment: To access a column using name you should use data frame instead of series. Try df = data[[data.columns[0]]]

Comment: that what i am doing in my code

Comment: ok i got it i added extra bracket it worked now

Answer (score 0):

The issue in these 2 lines

```
df1 = data[data.columns[0]]
df1.columns = ['code']
```

After 1st line, `df1` is a Series. Series has no attribute `columns`. On 2nd line, you tried to assign `['code']` to attribute `columns` of series `df1`. It doesn't exist so a new attribute `columns` got created in series `df1` with values `['code']`. This `columns` has nothing to do with the columns of pandas dataframe. It is just a custom attribute python created due to your assignment. When you call `df1.code.str.slice(0, 3)`, it can't find anything with name `code`, so it returns error.

I only fixed your code, so the fix is

```
df1 = data[[data.columns[0]]]
```

Now, `df1` is a dataframe and any following command will work.